# python diagrams package. How can we create subgraphs with rank attribute?

Tags: python, package, graphviz, diagram, dot

Hey guys I am trying to use the [python diagrams](https://github.com/mingrammer/diagrams) package. But I can't find out how to create subgraps and put the rank="same" attribute into them. In the dot language we can create subgraphs like this:

```
    subgraph co2graph {
        rank=same
        co2node1[style="filled", label="CO2"]
        co2node2[style="filled", label="CO2"]
        co2node3[style="filled", label="CO2"]
    }

or
subgraph cluster {
        // creates subgraph inside cluster (only subgraph can have rank)
        subgraph co2graphInsideCluster{
        rank=same
        co2node4[style="filled", label="CO2"]
        }
    }
```

But in the diagrams package all I can find is

```py
with Cluster(""):
        co2node = Node("CO2)
```

for getting stuff inside a cluster.

Anyone here knows how I could write the dot code using the python package? Would be a huge help!

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cluster inside a cluster, (this is what you mean by subgraph right?)

```
with Diagram("Event Processing", show=False):
    source = EKS("k8s source")

    with Cluster("Event Flows"):
        with Cluster("Event Workers"):
            workers = [ECS("worker1"),
                       ECS("worker2"),
                       ECS("worker3")]

        queue = SQS("event queue")

        with Cluster("Processing"):
            handlers = [Lambda("proc1"),
                        Lambda("proc2"),
                        Lambda("proc3")]

    source >> workers >> queue >> handlers
```

Cluster within a cluster:

[image: Cluster within a cluster]

## You can also use GraphViz dot attribute options

graph_attr, node_attr and edge_attr are supported. (Which includes Rank ig.)

```
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams.aws.compute import EC2

graph_attr = {
   "fontsize": "45",
   "bgcolor": "transparent"
}

with Diagram("Simple Diagram", show=False, graph_attr=graph_attr):
   EC2("web")
```